# Space in C drive is reducing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

After installing the Android Studio,free space in my C drive is reducing gradually.It has reduced to 11GB from 13 GB.How can I stop reducing my free space in C drive.Please help

Comment: It must be because the Android Studio (AS) downloaded Android SDK and it will need to download more of that when you download more APIs. You might be better off by Googling how you can see and change Android SDK path in AS.

Answer (score 1):

Sdk resid in c drive at below location:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\
```

move it to your d: or any other space.

Comment: and what about C:\Android\sdk\ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can move your sdk to other drive and link it with your studio

Comment: how to link it from other drive?can you guide me?

Comment: right click on project than select -> Open Module settings -> SDK Locatio ,get  location of drive where you have copied your sdk

Comment: I have to do it just one time or for each project,I have to do these steps?

Comment: Moreover,sdk is located at two locations.One is C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ and the other one is at C:\Android\sdk\ . which one should I move to other drive?

Comment: please check ehich sdk is used by your studio and what was the size of both move respectively my be your sdk is located at (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ ) so you cam move it

Answer (score -1):

Why do you relate the fact that storage space is diminishing with the installation of some software? 
Time coincidence is a weak indicator.
Of course, locally installing any software, including Android Studio, takes local disk space. Of course any software may get automatic updates and increase its storage needs over time. Of course if you are using the software intensively, it usually produces data that has to be stored somewhere (and it is usually stored locally), etc.
But I would start with an investigation WHAT data takes the increasing space on your disk. You can start with searching for big files, or with searching for recently modified files. Then you will find if Android Studio is really guilty here.